# Server not mapping Ajax to Servlet correctly when switched to java 1.7 and eclipse

Tags: java, ajax, eclipse, servlets, netbeans

TLDR: Do I have to use different syntax to access my servlet if I am using Tomcat instead of Glassfish or jkd 1.7 instead of jdk 1.8? I can't get my jquery ajax to communicate with my servlet (in eclipse 1.7 jdk tomcat instead of netbeans 1.8 jdk glassfish)

I am trying to convert my project from Netbeans 1.8 JDK to Eclipse 1.7 JKD.

It worked fine in Netbeans. I have spent over 5 hours trying to get it to function on Eclipse now.

I think the problem is that it is not mapping my ajax "search" to the servlet "/search" .

The servlet is annotated

```
@WebServlet(name = "SearchServlet", urlPatterns = {"/search"})
```

I have to assume this works with JDK 1.7.....?

I had trouble adding a glassfish server the same as my netbeans. I managed to add it but then it vanished and I had no server available whatsoever until I gave up and put in a tomcat one. However I don't know if you're supposed to configure this any further.

I try to add glassfish server tools by dragging it into my IDE but it says Nothing to update: nothing to update. So I'm just sticking with tomcat.

Here is the log when I run my jsp:

```
Apr 20, 2015 1:48:48 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:animelist1' did not find a matching property.
Apr 20, 2015 1:48:48 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.0.21
Apr 20, 2015 1:48:48 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          Mar 23 2015 14:11:21 UTC
Apr 20, 2015 1:48:48 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server number:         8.0.21.0
Apr 20, 2015 1:48:48 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Windows 7
Apr 20, 2015 1:48:48 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            6.1
Apr 20, 2015 1:48:48 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          amd64
Apr 20, 2015 1:48:48 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\jre
Apr 20, 2015 1:48:48 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           1.7.0_79-b15
Apr 20, 2015 1:48:48 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
Apr 20, 2015 1:48:48 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Users\J\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1
Apr 20, 2015 1:48:48 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-8.0.21
Apr 20, 2015 1:48:48 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\J\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1
Apr 20, 2015 1:48:48 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-8.0.21
Apr 20, 2015 1:48:48 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=C:\Users\J\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps
Apr 20, 2015 1:48:48 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-8.0.21\endorsed
Apr 20, 2015 1:48:48 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252
Apr 20, 2015 1:48:48 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\jdk1.7.0_79\bin;.
Apr 20, 2015 1:48:48 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Apr 20, 2015 1:48:48 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Apr 20, 2015 1:48:48 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Apr 20, 2015 1:48:48 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Apr 20, 2015 1:48:48 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 772 ms
Apr 20, 2015 1:48:48 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Apr 20, 2015 1:48:48 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.21
Apr 20, 2015 1:48:49 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Apr 20, 2015 1:48:49 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Apr 20, 2015 1:48:49 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Apr 20, 2015 1:48:49 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 1162 ms
```

Here is the log when I try to make a search by clicking the button on the jsp:

```
Apr 20, 2015 1:50:11 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Marking servlet SearchServlet as unavailable
Apr 20, 2015 1:50:11 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet SearchServlet
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [main.SearchServlet/annj] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [main.SearchServlet].
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:818)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.lookupFieldResource(DefaultInstanceManager.java:573)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.processAnnotations(DefaultInstanceManager.java:461)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:144)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:121)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1095)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:817)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:223)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1517)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1474)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Further searches after the first give this:

```
POST http://localhost:8080/animelist1/search 404 (Not Found)jQuery.ajaxTransport.send @ jquery-1.10.2.js:8706jQuery.extend.ajax @ jquery-1.10.2.js:8136(anonymous function) @ basic.js:8jQuery.event.dispatch @ jquery-1.10.2.js:5095jQuery.event.add.elemData.handle @ jquery-1.10.2.js:4766
```

I had to change my Environment variables to downgrade to JDK 1.7. I have put them below incase they are incorrect and are causing the issues (been messing around with them so much but I think they are right now):

(No added/changed User variables)

System variables:

Path

```
%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\jdk1.7.0_79\bin
```

JAVA_HOME

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79
```

I am about to give up and revert to Netbeans 1.8 JDK and upload my web project to somewhere other than Google App Engine (which only works with 1.7). I will give it another hour incase anyone is able to help me but I have spent far too long wasting my time when there is another option.

Like I said I suspect the problem is something to do with my server configuration or some file related to that. Below I will paste my ajax and my servlet. They do both work in netbeans 1.8 jdk but perhaps they need changing for eclipse 1.7 jdk?

Thankyou for reading!

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#searchForm').submit(function () {

        $.ajax({
            url: 'search',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'text',
            data: $('#searchForm').serialize(),
            success: function (data) {

                $('#displaySearchResults').html(data);
//                    $('#displaySearchResults').slideDown(500);
//                
                $("#sortable1").empty();

                $.each(JSON.parse(data), function (listID, mapData) {

                    $("#sortable1").append(
                            "<li class=userList><div class=selectedItemId id=" + mapData.id + "><img class=selectedItemImg src=" 
                            + mapData.url + " alt=" + mapData.name 
                            + " style='width:216px;height:300px'></img><div id='animeTitle'>"
                            + mapData.name+ "</div></div></li>");


//                    <ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable">
//            <li class="ui-state-default">Item 1</li>

//                    var d1 = mapData.id;
//                    var d2 = d1.replace("'","");
//                    var div = document.createElement(d2);
//                    document.body.appendChild(div);


//                    $("#"+divName).text(mapData.id);
//                    $("#displaySearchResults2").text(mapData.name);
//                    $("#displaySearchResults3").text(mapData.url);

                });
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Servlet

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package main;

import com.google.common.collect.ArrayListMultimap;
import com.google.common.collect.ListMultimap;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import entities.Anime;
import entities.Ann;
import entities.Info;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 *
 * @author J
 */
@WebServlet(name = "SearchServlet", urlPatterns = {"/search"})
public class SearchServlet extends HttpServlet {

        /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @EJB
    private AnnJAXB annj;

//    @EJB
//    private AnnJAXB annJAXB = new AnnJAXB();

    @EJB
    private Ann ann;

    /**
     * Processes requests for both HTTP <code>GET</code> and <code>POST</code>
     * methods.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
            /* TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code. */
            out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
            out.println("<html>");
            out.println("<head>");
            out.println("<title>Servlet SearchServlet</title>");            
            out.println("</head>");
            out.println("<body>");
            out.println("<h1>Servlet SearchServlet at " + request.getContextPath() + "</h1>");
            out.println("</body>");
            out.println("</html>");
        }
    }

    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">
    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>GET</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

//        processRequest(request, response);

//        Map <String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        String searchQuery = request.getParameter("searchQuery");
//         response.getWriter().write(searchQuery);

//        map.put("searchQuery", searchQuery);
//        returnResults(response, map);

        returnResults(response, searchQuery);

    }

    private void returnResults(HttpServletResponse response, String searchQuery) throws IOException {

        response.setContentType("text/html");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

        ArrayList<Map> arrayOfMap = new ArrayList<Map>();

        try {
            for (Anime anime : annj.Unmarshalling(searchQuery).getAnn()) {

                Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                map.put("name", anime.getName());
                map.put("id", anime.getId());

                for (Info temp : anime.getAnime()) {
                    if (temp.getSrc() != null) {

                        map.put("url", temp.getSrc());
                    }
                }
                arrayOfMap.add(map);


            }

              response.getWriter().write(new Gson().toJson(arrayOfMap));

        } catch (Exception e) {}
    }


    /**
     * Returns a short description of the servlet.
     *
     * @return a String containing servlet description
     */
    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }// </editor-fold>

}
```

TLDR: Do I have to use different syntax to access my servlet if I am using Tomcat instead of Glassfish or jkd 1.7 instead of jdk 1.8? I can't get my jquery ajax to communicate with my servlet (in eclipse 1.7 jdk tomcat instead of netbeans 1.8 jdk glassfish)

Comment: It has nothing to do with the version of Java. @WebServlet is a JEE annotation, not a standard JDK annotation. And since its a standard, it works the same in Tomcat and Glassfish. Likely the only problem you have is that the application deployment in your secondary Eclipse isn't working properly yet. As in: the servlet class file is not deployed to the server at all.

Comment: Thankyou for your answer. I've been working so long and I think we are close. I figured out what you said just now. I have a "feeling" it could be something to do with me needing to re-specify the main/base/root location... i say this because in netbeans version i access the jsp by going to http://localhost:8080/ or http://localhost:8080/index.jsp , whereas in eclipse version i need to go to http://localhost:8080/animelist1.index.jsp or http://localhost:8080/animelist1 . for eclipse, going to http://localhost:8080/ 404s . Why might this be? Thankyou!!!

Comment: I added <context-root>/</context-root> to my server.xml file and the page loads at localhost:8080 HOWEVER it now opens at http://localhost:8080/animelist1/ . This means something different needs to be configured to tell it where to "start looking" for things....

Answer (score 0):

As I know , the notation

> @WebServlet(name = "SearchServlet", urlPatterns = {"/search"})

only work in jdk 1.8
but if you still use jdk 1.7, forget the notation and fill web.xml with this map

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>search</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>yourPackage.search</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>search</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/search</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```